# How to add a variable which pick up certain value dependent on other variable present in view.py in django

Tags: python, django

I want to make form2 variable in which we have to add condition that pick institute name from register table where institute code is equal to institute code present in form 1 variable and pass form2 in context so that it can be printed in template file.

I have added code in view.py

```
def view_eligibility_admin(request):
form1 = Eligibility_Check.objects.all() 
form2 = {}  # Initialize an empty dictionary to store institute names
    for item in form1:
institute_code = item.Centre_code
        try:
            register_entry = Register.objects.get(institute_code=institute_code) 
            institute_name = register_entry.institute_name
            form2[institute_code] = institute_name
        except Register.DoesNotExist:
              # Handle the case where the institute code doesn't exist in the Register model
            form2[institute_code] = "N/A"
    context = {'form1': form1, 'form2': form2}
    return render(request, 'view_eligibiity_admin.html', context)
```

In my template.py I have used it like this.

````
               <tr>
                   <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
                   <td>{{ i.Centre_code }} / {{ i.Serial_number }}</td>
                   <td>{{ i.Date_of_survey }}</td>
                   <td>{{ i.District }}</td>
                   <td>{{ i.Voter_id }}</td>
                   <td>{{ i.Ec }}</td>
                   <td>{{ form2.item.institute_code }}</td>               
                   <td class="text-center">
                       <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'view_eligibility_pid' i.pk %}"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a> 
                   </td>
               </tr>
               {% endfor %}```
But i am getting blank value in place of institute name.
````

Comment: One thing I can infer from your code is that you might be lacking foreign keys. Why aren't you accessing the related objects by directly using a [foreign key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)?

Answer (score 0):

From the code what I can infer that form1 is object list of Eligibility_Check
You want to append one more value based on conditions in your Eligibility_Check object.

Better way to add the additional value in existing object itself.
Modify the code this way to do this

in views.py

```
def view_eligibility_admin(request):
    form1 = Eligibility_Check.objects.all() 
        for item in form1:
            institute_code = item.Centre_code
            try:
                register_entry = Register.objects.get(institute_code=institute_code) 
                institute_name = register_entry.institute_name
                item.institute_code = institute_name
            except Register.DoesNotExist:
                # Handle the case where the institute code doesn't exist in the Register model
                item.institute_code = "N/A"
        context = {'form1': form1}
    return render(request, 'view_eligibiity_admin.html', context)
```

in template.py

```
        <tr>
            <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
            <td>{{ i.Centre_code }} / {{ i.Serial_number }}</td>
            <td>{{ i.Date_of_survey }}</td>
            <td>{{ i.District }}</td>
            <td>{{ i.Voter_id }}</td>
            <td>{{ i.Ec }}</td>
            <td>{{ i.institute_code }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'view_eligibility_pid' i.pk %}"><i class="fa fa-eye"
                        aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
```